# How to detect UDP socket receive buffer overflow from application?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp

When the application does not recv the datagrams fast enough, receive buffer gets exhausted and packets get dropped, incrementing `/proc/net/snmp`'s `InErrors` counter.

How the receiving application can know that some datagrams are skipped because of the application is itself too slow recv'ing them? Reading `/proc/net/snmp` from the application is bad idea...

Comment: Do you have a sequence number in the datagrams you're receiving ? If not can you add that ?

Comment: There are multiple sequence numbers and timestamps in the datagrams (the program's job is to test network connection and detect UDP packet loss depending on various rates and packet sizes), but I want to distriminate between packet loss due to networking and due to the receiving program slowness.

Comment: There's a SO_RXQ_OVFL socket option you can set, which seems to deliver overflow counters via the socket error queue, and possibly you can read it directly with getsockopt too. Unfortunately I can't find any usable documentation for it...